# detect if telegram client installed via browser js

Tags: javascript, telegram

Is there any way to detect from site javascript, if telegram client installed, and what type of client (mobile, desktop, web) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in modern browsers, but you can try to open `tg://` URL directly, just like what t.me do.